# How can I access a Java constructor in a generic way?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, generics, parameterized

I have a static builder method for a class "Model" that takes a JSON string and returns an ArrayList of Models. I would like it refer to the Model's constructer generically so that subclasses can inherit the builder method.

```
public class Model
{
    protected int id;

    public Model(String json) throws JSONException 
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        this.id = jsonObject.getInt("id");
    }

    public static <T extends Model> ArrayList<T> build(String json) throws JSONException
    {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);

        ArrayList<T> models = new ArrayList<T>(jsonArray.length());

        for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
            models.add( new T(jsonArray.get(i)) )

        return models;
    }
}
```

This is a simplified implementation of the class, the relevant line being

```
models.add( new T(jsonArray.get(i)) )
```

I know this isn't possible, but I would like to write something that calls the constructor of whatever type T happens to be. I have tried to use this(), which obviously doesn't work because the method "build" is static and I've tried to use reflection to determine the class of T but have been at a loss to figure out how to get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Roy

Comment: How do you decide what subclass you need? That decision needs to be formulated and written in code somehow. Is the decision based on the return value from jsonArray.get(i)? (What does that method return, anyway?)

Answer (score 1):

The workaround for "dynamic instantiation" with generics is to pass a hint to the class or the method:

```
public class Model<T> {
  Class<T> hint;
  public Model(Class<T> hint) {this.hint = hint;}

  public T getObjectAsGenericType(Object input, Class<T> hint) throws Exception {
    return hint.cast(input);
  }

  public T createInstanceOfGenericType(Class<T> hint) throws Exception {
    T result = hint.newInstance();
    result.setValue(/* your JSON object here */);
    return result;
  }
}
```

I'm happy to provide more help/ideas but I'm not sure what you want to *achieve* with your technical solution.

(Note: Example has some over-simplified Exception handling)

Answer (score 0):

The way it is written now, I can't see that the T type parameter in build() is of any use whatsoever. Can't you just drop it and use Model in its place? If so, that would solve your construction problem.

Comment: If I call "new Model(json)", will that translate to the subclass of Model when I inherit from it? I'll try that now and see

Comment: No, it will not. But the static build() has no way of knowing what subclass to instantiate, so a different approach is needed.